# CAShapeLayer with gradient

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a problem with adding gradient to CAShapeLayer. I've created circle layer and I want to add a gradient to it. So, I created a CAGradientLayer and set it frames to layer bounds and mask to layer and it doesn't appear. What can I do?

```
private func setupCircle() -> CAShapeLayer {
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: progressView.frame.size.width / 2.0, y: progressView.frame.size.height / 2.0), radius: (progressView.frame.size.width - 10)/2, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), clockwise: true)

    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    circleLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath
    circleLayer.fillColor = nil
    circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
    circleLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
    circleLayer.lineWidth = configurator.lineWidth
    circleLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0

    return circleLayer
}

private func setupGradient() -> CAGradientLayer {
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.25, 1.0]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1)
    return gradient
}

let circle = setupCircle()
let gradient = setupGradient()

gradient.frame = circle.bounds
gradient.mask = circle

progressView.layer.addSublayer(circle)
progressView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
```

**EDIT:**
I've changed setupCircle method to:

```
private func setupCircle() -> CAShapeLayer {
    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    circleLayer.frame = progressView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 5, dy: 5)
    circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(progressView.center.x, progressView.center.y, progressView.bounds.size.width, progressView.bounds.size.height)).CGPath
    circleLayer.fillColor = nil
    circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
    circleLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
    circleLayer.lineWidth = configurator.lineWidth
    circleLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0

    return circleLayer
}
```

And here the effect, did I do it properly?:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
I've changed `circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(progressView.center.x, progressView.center.y, progressView.bounds.size.width, progressView.bounds.size.height)).CGPath` to `circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: circleLayer.bounds).CGPath` and it's better but still not what I want:

[image]

Comment: What is the scope of this line `let circle = setupCircle()` and the code below? is it an instance variable or local variable in `viewDidLoad` or something?

Comment: It's in setup method which is called in viewDidLoad

Comment: Check the updated answer, it should fix your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok that you create layers and add them to layer hierarchy in `viewDidLoad`, but you shouldn't do any frame logic there since layout is not updated at that moment. 
Try to move all the code which is doing any frame calculations  to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

This should also be done every time layout is updated, so move it from `setupCircle` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(...)
circleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
```

**Edit:**

Also I can't see where do you set `circleLayer`'s frame? It's not enough to set it's path. If you have CGRect.zero rect for a mask, it will completely hide it's parent layer.

I would recommend to replace this:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: progressView.frame.size.width / 2.0, y: progressView.frame.size.height / 2.0), radius: (progressView.frame.size.width - 10)/2, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), clockwise: true)
```

with this:

```
circleLayer.bounds = progressView.frame.insetBy(dx: 5, dy: 5)
circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: circleLayer.bounds).cgPath
```

This way you'll have both frame and path set. Also be careful about coordinate system. I'm not sure about where is `progressView` in your view hierarchy, perhaps you'll need it's `bounds` instead.

**Edit 2:**
Also you should delete a few lines of code there.

1. This makes your circle layer completely opaque, it makes the shape itself unvisible.

```
circleLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
```

2. You shouldn't add circle as a sublayer since you're going to use it as a mask:

```
progressView.layer.addSublayer(circle)
```

Comment: It still doesn't appear

Comment: Just found another mistake. Make sure you set a frame for `mask` layer

Comment: Thanks, I didn't set frame to layer. How can I set a frame basing on path?

Comment: @Woodgun11 You should rather calculate frame first and then create a `path` based on that frame.

Comment: Try `UIBezierPath(ovalIn: circleLayer.bounds).cgPath` instead. You don't need `progressView.frame` there anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126423/discussion-between-alexburtnik-and-woodgun11).